# Why is my function returning a Unit instead of Int?

Tags: scala, return-type

I am new to Scala and working on a project. I am writing a function that is suppose to return the smallest `Int` in an array. However when I run it I get a type error that it is returning unit instead of int.

Here is my code:

```
def minWhile(r: Array[Int]): Int = {
  var pos = 1
  var minInt = r(0)

  while (pos < r.length) {
    if (r(pos) < minInt)
      minInt = r(pos)

    pos += 1
  }

  minInt
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your code work both on my Scala console and IntelliJ IDE

Comment: Your code seems fine; although it expects a non-empty list and is a little imperative maybe. Can you add the actual error you get?

Comment: I suspect in your actual code you forgot the = between `Int` and `{`.  Please do post the actual code that gives the error, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is compiled correctly, because it always returns correct type Int. But it may cause some runtime exceptions, if we passed empty array into your function: minWhile(Array()).

```
def minWhile(r: Array[Int]): Int =
  {
    var pos = 1
    var minInt = r(0)    /* potential runtime exception */
      while( pos < r.length){
        if(r(pos) < minInt)
          minInt = r(pos)
        pos+=1

      }
    minInt
  }
```

You have to check arrays bounds working with it.
Or you can use a shorter way:

```
def minWhile(r: Array[Int]): Option[Int] = if (r.nonEmpty) Some(r.min) else None
```

Comment: I forgot to check for empty arrays. That was probably the cause of my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be compiled correctly but it may rise an exception when passed empty container. You are using variables which is discouraged.

I would do it using some recursion calls or scala collections API like so:

```
array.reduceLeft(a: Somehitng, b: Something => Something)
```

Check thia link:

http://m.alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-use-reduceleft-get-max-min-from-collection

Answer (score 0):

Consider this more functional style of conveying the semantics of `minWhile`, as follows,

```
def minWhile(r: Array[Int]): Int = {
  (r zip r.drop(1)).takeWhile(t => t._1 > t._2).last._2
}
```

where we zip consecutive items and `take` those monotonically decreasing. The desired result is found in the second part of the last duple.